# Accidentally installed apache over nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, debian, vps

I currently run a server with WordOps (wordops.net). With WordOps you get nginx installed automatically.

Early this morning I was trying install mautic on my server and I followed a copy and paste tutorial on how to do it, but only at the end I noticed the tutorial was for Apache. Instantly all my sites got HTTP 500 error status. So, I uninstalled Apache and started nginx again and then all returned to normal. However, I decided to use the command "apt-get upgrade -y" after it and then nginx stopped working. So, I tried to uninstall nginx completely and install again using WordOps. But then I get this error

```
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:29,885 (INFO) wo : Initializing WordOps Database[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:29,888 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting apt_packages variable for Nginx[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:29,888 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting apt_packages variable for PHP 7.3[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,662 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mPHP 7.3 already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:30,663 (INFO) wo : [94mPHP 7.3 already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,663 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting apt_packages variable for MySQL[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,663 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mRunning command: mysqladmin ping[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,674 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mCommand Output: mysqld is alive
,
Command Error: [0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,674 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mMySQL already installed and alive[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:30,674 (INFO) wo : [94mMySQL already installed and alive[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,674 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting packages variable for WP-CLI[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,675 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mWP-CLI is already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:30,675 (INFO) wo : [94mWP-CLI is already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:30,675 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting apt_packages variable for Fail2ban[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:31,537 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mFail2ban already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:31,538 (INFO) wo : [94mFail2ban already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:31,538 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting apt_packages variable for Sendmail[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,378 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSendmail already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (INFO) wo : [94mSendmail already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mphpMyAdmin already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (INFO) wo : [94mphpMyAdmin already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mphpRedisAdmin already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (INFO) wo : [94mphpRedisAdmin already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mComposer already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,379 (INFO) wo : [94mComposer already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mAdminer already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (INFO) wo : [94mAdminer already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mMySQLtuner already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (INFO) wo : [94mMySQLtuner already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mNetdata already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (INFO) wo : [94mNetdata already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting packages variable for WO-Dashboard[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95meXtplorer is already installed[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (INFO) wo : [94meXtplorer is already installed[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,380 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mRunning command: mysqladmin ping[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:33,405 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mCommand Output: mysqld is alive
,
Command Error: [0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:35,235 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mSetting packages variable for utils[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:35,235 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mCalling pre_pref[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:35,235 (INFO) wo : [94mAdding repository for NGINX, please wait...[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:35,236 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mAdding repository for Nginx[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:35,236 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mRunning command: apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 188C9FB063F0247A[0m
[36m2021-03-23 16:56:36,359 (DEBUG) wo.core.logging : [95mCommand Output: Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.JdYbpTDxew/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 188C9FB063F0247A
,
Command Error: Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: key 188C9FB063F0247A: "home:virtubox OBS Project <home:virtubox@build.opensuse.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: unchanged: 1
[0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:36,359 (INFO) wo : [94mUpdating apt-cache [0m
[32m2021-03-23 16:56:38,500 (INFO) wo : [94m[91mWhoops, something went wrong...[0m
[31m2021-03-23 16:56:38,500 (ERROR) wo : [91mCheck the WordOps log for more details tail /var/log/wo/wordops.log and please try again...[0m
```

When I try to install nginx using apt-get install nginx-full I get this error

```
 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "more_set_headers" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
```

When I use apt-get install nginx-extras I get this error

```
[emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I'm kinda desperate lol
Any help will be truly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

means there's a process already using port 80 which is the port used by a web server to serve http content. The process might be apache, nginx or any other service you're running.

Chech the status of nginx/apache and if it's stopped check which service is listening on port 80:

```
sudo netstat -tupan | grep -i list
```

you will show an output similar to this:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      574/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      12431/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      12431/apache2
```

which means the process with pid 12431 is listening on port 80 and 443. The process is called apache2.
If the name is not shown, you can find it out with ps:

```
 ps aux | grep 12431
```

The output will look like the following:

```
root      12431  0.0  2.3 238408 22796 ?        Ss   Mar10  10:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

which means the process '/usr/sbin/apache2' is the one you're looking for.

Once you've found out what process is preventing nginx to start, you should terminate it with kill command or systemctl (or whatever you're using).

Once the port has been freed, you can try starting nginx again.